# APNS Push Notifications not being delivered to *some* devices

Tags: ios, django, apple-push-notifications

I developed a web API for my mobile app use it.

This API was developed with Django, and I'm using the django-push-notifications lib to handle the push notifications.

The push notifications were working fine for all the devices, until it stopped working for **few of them, which worked at some point,** for no apparent reason.

I already debugged the server and **I can see the messages being sent to APNS and on the correct format**. Also reviewed the certificates, and all is working as it should. I'm using the production certificate sending to the appropriate server.
**I'm sure that this is not a problem with certs, since some other phones receive the notifications.**

Where should I start looking for the problem now?

Thanks.

Comment: Do all devices have the same app version installed in terms debug/release??

Answer (score 3):

1. They are not reliable! There is no guarantee that push notifications will actually be delivered, even if the APNS server accepted them.
   As far as your server is concerned, push notifications are fire-and-forget; there is no way to find out what the status of a notification is after you’ve sent it to APNS. The delivery time may also vary, from seconds up to half an hour.
2. Also, the user’s iPhone may not be able to receive push notifications all the time. They could be on a WiFi network that does not allow connections to be made to APNS because the required ports are blocked. Or the phone could be turned off.

[See this link](http://www.raywenderlich.com/32960/apple-push-notification-services-in-ios-6-tutorial-part-1)

Comment: 1 - Why do this happens only to some users? And consistently to those users, while others are working fine? I don't think that's a coincidence

2 - The iphone was able to receive it at some point and stopped working. The conditions haven't changed.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure that those *some* devices does't have a development version of app ?

Try to generate a combined p12 certificate of apn development certificate and apn production certificate , than try to call gateway.push.apple.com and gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com separately.